# Is it possible to tell a render prop appart from a ReactNode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I am making a reusable component that currently accepts a ReactNode. However I would also like to have it accept a render prop function. However I think just checking if `typeof propName === "function"` to distinguish the two options would not work since a ReactNode might be a functional component. So my question is whether there is a property defined on functional components that would allow me to tell them appart from a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about the ReactNode. Looking at the definition it's actually never a function. So `typeof propName === "function"` should work.